# Ending a redigo process

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I'm working on a chat server and am using redigo in order to publish messages across many web socket connections. I have a go routine that (per user connection) opens  a connection to redis, subscribes to some channels and waits for a message.  Waiting for this message -

```
msg := psc.Receive()
```

is a blocking operation in the fact that any code after the receive function will not run until a message comes in. However I would like to be able to watch for context -

```
ctx.Done()
```

or the like. Is this achievable using a select, or is there a more idiomatic way of writing this? I am attempting to do this as in the current implementation this function is run as a go routine, and if the web session ends I would like to end the redis connection and finish the go routine.

```
func relayRedisMessages (ctx context.Context, ws *websocket.Conn, rc []string) {

    c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()

    psc := redis.PubSubConn{c}

    for _, channel := range rc {
        psc.Subscribe(channel)
    }

    for {
        msg := psc.Receive()
        // Write message to websocket
        var msg Message
        json.Unmarshal(v.Data, &msg)
        err = ws.WriteJSON(msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsubscribe the connection when done, exit the receive loop when subscription count goes to zero.  Redigo has example that covers this and more.

Comment: Another issue to consider is that your design creates one redis connection for each client connection.  This works for a few connection, but will not scale to  thousands of connections.  A better approach is to multiplex the subscriptions over a single redis connection.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I handle the psc and the subscribes outside of the go routine, then pass options through to .Receive that cause it to close when no more subs? In regards to the multiple redis clients - are you able to have multiple private chat streams via one redis client? Seems to make more sense to have them seperately to leverage the tidy way it sends messages to those subscribed

Comment: I am not suggesting a specific way to structure the code. The key point is that unsubscribe is the way to break out of the receive loop. Yes, you can demux multiple chat streams in process.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll try to knock together a prototype for future reference